# Keeping the password when migrating users from MSAD to RHDS

Tags: active-directory, security, ldap

I need to migrate users from the aforementoned platforms and the ideal situation would be that the users continued to authenticate with the same passwords. Is it doable by just copying the hashes? If not what additional steps should be taken?

Comment: Don't. It would be better to take the opportunity to educate the users in creating good and memorable pass phrases (https://www.xkcd.com/936/) and have them practice by setting one up with their brand new account under the new security system.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, this is not possible.

Your options:

- Intercept password changes with a DLL installed in the AD domain controllers. Many AD admins do not like this. Also it's slow depending on how long users' password are valid.
- Intercept password authentication in an application where users enter their clear-text passwords. Slightly faster but 100% user coverage is not guaranteed either.
- Force users to go through a password reset process on your RHDS installation.